# Subset of Pareto/powerlaw distribution

Tags: distributions, random-generation, subset, pareto-distribution

Given a set of random data generated using pareto-distribution, how can I get X% of this random data without losing pareto-distribution.

In other words, how to select a subset of pareto-distribution without affecting distribution function.

Comment: You want to take a sample of your data & have it still be distributed as a Pareto?

Comment: Yes - is it doable?